# Prisma assigning types that I did not delcare

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, prisma

I have a many to many relationship between Post and Upload and prisma is claiming upload.posts is of type never. Due to this I cannot query a relationship I need. I am not sure why Prisma is assigning type never to this. See the below findFirst statement I am trying to use to connect a upload to a post.

```js
await prisma.upload.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: upload.id,
  },
  select: {
    type: true,
  },

  // prisma claims posts is Type never
  posts: {
    connect: {
      id: post.id
    }
  }
});
```

Schema for relationships

```
model Upload {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  uploads Upload[]
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your use case? You cannot use connect while performing a find query. And I see you are selecting type but that's not a part of your model.

Comment: I am trying to query an Upload ID and attach it to the Post using the many to many schema.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Prisma documentation to see how you can use `findFirst`:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#get-the-first-record-that-matches-a-specific-criteria

You cannot pass `posts` as a top-level argument to `findFirst`. You can't make changes to data as you are querying for it, if that is what you are trying to do.

```js
await prisma.upload.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: upload.id,
  },
  // REMOVED: "type", your model does not have a "type" field
  select: {
    id: true,
  }
  // REMOVED: "posts"
});
```